# better way to automate the loops in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this

```
user = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','101','101','102','102','101','101','102','102','102'],'Country':['India','Japan','India','Brazil','Japan','UK','Austria','Japan','Singapore','UK'],'Count':[50,1,2,5,6,89,10.9,10,5,6]})
```

and i am doing this calculations

```
def group(df):
    if df['Percentile'] < 33:
        return 1
    elif df['Percentile'] < 66:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3

user_101 = user[user['User'] == '101']
user_101['Percentile'] = user_101['Count'].rank(pct= True,ascending=True).mul(100)
user_101['group'] = user_101.apply(group,axis=1)

user_102 = user[user['User'] == '102']
user_102['Percentile'] = user_102['Count'].rank(pct=True,ascending=True).mul(100)
user_102['group'] = user_102.apply(group,axis=1)

user_v2 = pd.concat([user_101,user_102],axis=0)
```

like this i have so many users how to do these calculations in a function and loop though all users?

i am looking for improvements in the code. as here i am doing first separate out the data frames for each user and doing the calculations is there way to just pass the user id and will get the desired output user_v2 dataframe?

Thanks.

Comment: what's the expected output here?

Comment: expected output is my user_v2 dataframe. i am looking for improvements in the code. as here i am doing it seperate out the dataframes for each user and doing the calculations is there way to just pass the user id and will get the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform the operations for all users by first performing a `groupby`. Then instead of applying your function row-wise use `np.select` to assign the groups.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

user['Percentile'] = user.groupby('User').Count.rank(pct=True, ascending=True)*100
user['group'] = np.select([user.Percentile<33, user.Percentile<66, user.Percentile>=66], [1,2,3])
```

`user` is now:

```
   Count    Country User  Percentile  group
0   50.0      India  101        80.0      3
1    1.0      Japan  101        20.0      1
2    2.0      India  101        40.0      2
3    5.0     Brazil  102        30.0      1
4    6.0      Japan  102        70.0      3
5   89.0         UK  101       100.0      3
6   10.9    Austria  101        60.0      2
7   10.0      Japan  102       100.0      3
8    5.0  Singapore  102        30.0      1
9    6.0         UK  102        70.0      3
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. just wanted to check is there way where we can pass the keyword parameters? . Actually i am a SAS user and recently started python. In SAS Macros we just pass the paarmeters and it will  do the calculations  like this example.%macro finance(yvar=expenses,xvar=division);
   proc plot data=yearend;
      plot &yvar*&xvar;
   run;
%mend finance;

Comment: @KumarAK I don't know SAS at all, so I can't help there. You might want to ask another question and tag it properly to attract the correct help.

Comment: @KumarAK, the pandas documentation has a comparison with sas, although it doesn't seem to cover macros: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sas.html

Answer (score 1):

you can get the percentile using group by on `User` and the `rank` function, and since you assign group ranks of 1,2,3 based on equal division of the percentiles you could alternatively multiply by 3 & use `math.ceil` or `numpy.ceil`

```
user['Percentile'] = user.groupby('User').Count.rank(pct=True) * 100
user['group'] = (user.Percentile * 3 / 100).apply(np.ceil)
```

produces output:

```
  User    Country  Count  Percentile  group
0  101      India   50.0        80.0      3
1  101      Japan    1.0        20.0      1
2  101      India    2.0        40.0      2
3  102     Brazil    5.0        30.0      1
4  102      Japan    6.0        70.0      3
5  101         UK   89.0       100.0      3
6  101    Austria   10.9        60.0      2
7  102      Japan   10.0       100.0      3
8  102  Singapore    5.0        30.0      1
9  102         UK    6.0        70.0      3
```